# Difference between object.method() and method(object) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, methods

I have a very basic question; if this is a duplicate please link me to it as I wasn’t sure what to search!

I’d like the ask what the difference between `object.method()` and `method(object)` is. For instance, when I was defining a stack class, I noticed that `peek(stack)` returned name error while `stack.peek()` worked fine. Why is this so? Please forgive me is this is a duplicate, will remove this question if so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this class definition:

```
# foo.py

class Stack(object):
    def peek(self):
        return 42
```

The `peek` function, being declared in the `class` statement block, becomes an attribute of the `Stack` class and not a module global of the `foo` module, so you cannot access it directly - you need to look it up on `Stack`, ie:

```
# foo.py continued

obj = Stack()


try:
    peek(obj)
except NameError:
    print("peek is not a module-level function")

Stack.peek(obj)
# or more simply
obj.peek()
```