# What is the difference between these two examples

Tags: python, class, difference

I'm pretty beginner at coding and have coded a few simple games, but just now i have started to learn classes. I'm not sure what's the difference between

```
user.walk()
```

and

```
Person.walk(user)
```

Here is the class definition:

```
class Person():
def __init__(self, age, weight, height, first_name, last_name):
    self.age = age
    self.weight = weight
    self.height = height
    self.first_name = first_name
    self.last_name = last_name
def walk(self):
    print('Walking')
```

Here i define who is user:

```
user = Person(13, 50, 170, 'First name', 'Last name')
```

So if anybody has time to answer this question, please help me understand this.

Comment: There is *almost no* difference. The former is just a more concise (or more OOP) way of calling.

Comment: The one big difference is that the first way is the proper "Pythonic" way of doing it.  The second way would never be used in ordinary code, only is special circumstances that you are unlikely to encounter.

Comment: there's a case where sometimes the second approach is highly useful. for example `object.__setattr__` to call the base super class setattr method rather than the class's one. however, largely this won't be needed at least in the general use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between object.method() and method(object) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328984/difference-between-object-method-and-methodobject-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is basically no difference. `user.walk()` will end up translating to, effectively, `Person.walk(user)` but is more readable to the average programmer, not to mention idiomatic.

Specifically, what happens if this. `Person.walk(user)` is just an ordinary function call on an ordinary function. No magic here. But when Python sees

```
user.walk()
```

and there's no `walk` on the `user` object (since it's not defined as an instance variable on the object itself), then Python will look on the class. Specifically, it will convert `user.walk()` into

```
type(user).walk.__get__(user, type(user))()
```

And function objects in Python have a `__get__` method which converts them to *bound method* objects, so this effectively becomes

```
(lambda: Person.walk(user))()
```

which is, by [eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion),

```
Person.walk(user)
```

Python does all of this behind the scenes, so you don't have to worry about it unless you're doing some advanced metaprogramming.